# Trie Backtracking in Recursion

Tags: python, spell-checking, trie

I am building a tree for a spell checker with suggestions. Each node contains a key (a letter) and a value (array of letters down that path).

So assume the following sub-trie in my big trie:

```
                W
               / \
              a   e
              |   |
              k   k
              |   |
   is word--> e   e
                  |
                 ...
```

*This is just a subpath of a sub-trie. W is a node and a and e are two nodes in its value array etc...*

At each node, I check if the next letter in the word is a value of the node. I am trying to support mistyped vowels for now. So 'weke' will yield 'wake' as a suggestion. Here's my `searchWord` function in my trie:

```
def searchWord(self, word, path=""):

    if len(word) > 0:
        key = word[0]
        word = word[1:]

        if self.values.has_key(key):
            path = path + key
            nextNode = self.values[key]
            return nextNode.searchWord(word, path)

        else:
             # check here if key is a vowel. If it is, check for other vowel substitutes

    else:
        if self.isWord:
            return path # this is the word found
        else:
            return None
```

Given 'weke', at the end when word is of length zero and path is 'weke', my code will hit the second big else block. `weke` is not marked as a word and so it will return with None. This will return out of `searchWord` with None.

To avoid this, at each stack unwind or recursion backtrack, I need to check if a letter is a vowel and if it is, do the checking again.

I changed the `if self.values.has_key(key)` loop to the following:

```
 if self.values.has_key(key):
    path = path + key
    nextNode = self.values[key]
    ret = nextNode.searchWord(word, path)

    if ret == None:
        # check if key == vowel and replace path
        # return nextNode.searchWord(...

    return ret
```

What am I doing wrong here? What can I do when backtracking to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search recursively. Keep track of the current index and the original word.

```
letters = [chr(i) for i in range(97,97+26)]
print letters
max = 300

def searchWord(orig,word, curindex,counter):
    if counter>max: return

    if counter==0:
        s = letters[0] + word[1:]            
        searchWord(orig,s,0,counter+1)
    else:
        c = word[curindex]

        print 'checking ',word,curindex
        s = word
        i = letters.index(c)

        if i==len(letters)-1 and curindex==len(orig)-1:
            print 'done'
            return

        if i==len(letters)-1: 
            print 'end of letters reached'
            print 'curindex',curindex
            s = list(word)
            s[curindex] = list(orig)[curindex]
            s[curindex+1] = letters[0]
            s[1] = letters[0]
            s = ''.join(s)
            searchWord(orig,s,curindex+1,counter+1)

        else:
            s = list(word)
            try:
                s[curindex] = letters[i+1]
            except:
                print '?? ',s,curindex,letters[i]

            s = ''.join(s)
            searchWord(orig,s ,curindex,counter+1)


searchWord("weke","weke",0,0)
```

---

I'm not sure recursion and tree-search is the right approach here. If you have a table of words in your memory, the loopkup will be very fast. It is only when the search space is so big, that one has has to split the problem. So the better algorithm will be probably simply something like this:

```
corpus_words = {'wake',....} # this is in memory
allowed = word in corpus_words # perhaps improve this with adjusted binary search
```

A typical [corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus%20corpus) has 5-30 million words, which is less than 1 Gigabyte. Lookup will be very fast because you can do binary search, which is O(log n) in the average case. The problem with searching for a subset of the word is that you don't know that the typed words is not a word. However you could build allowed vowels. Certain combinations of letters won't be in the corpus. So in terms of computation this problem is pretty easy nowadays. Of course one can quickly improve the simple lookup, by keeping a core corpus in memory, and the rest on disk. Swipe on android works pretty well. It uses a personalized corpus and some machine learning.

What I would do to solve this particular problem, is to calulate neighbours of the word 'weke' and check if they are in the corpus, i.e.

```
word = 'weke'             
suggestions = list()                                                      
letters = [chr(x) for x in range(97,97+26)]                                     
for i in range(len(word)):                                                      
    for a in letters: # or do this in a smarter way to iterate                                                           
        newword = word                                                          
        newword[i] = a                                                          
        if newword in corpus: suggestions.append(newword)
```

And then to improve it, check subsections if they are in a corpus of syllables. There is a lot of work, which has been done on this front so you can probably find standard solutions on the internet, for example: http://nltk.org/

Comment: Just a question about your underlying data structure, would it be a dictionary or a list? I see you used `{}` but I don't understand what the values of they keys would be. I'm assuming then it's just a list of words? As for the suggestion, you're suggesting I can do every possible change on the very word itself and then just look it up if it exists in the table?

Comment: 1. Yes, that would be list or a hastable perhaps (you could try hd5). 2. Yes, every iteration has to be verified against a corpus. By checking the syllables this can be done more efficiently. For example (*zzz*) is probably not in a corpus for english, no matter what * is. To do this very efficiently is probably a lot of work, so it might be much easier to find existing solutions or at least algorithms in pseduo code etc.